# MQTT to Kafka. How to avoid duplicates

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, mqtt, publish-subscribe

My requirement is to load balance 2 MQTT nodes running on different VMs and then having consumers to these MQTT brokers on both nodes. The job of the consumers will be to subscribe on one topic and after receiving the data, publish it to Kafka. Problem I see if that since both MQTT consumers are subscribed on the same topic, they will receive the same message and both will insert it into Kafka thereby creating duplicates. is there anyway to avoid writing duplicates into Kafka?

- I have tried Mosquitto and Mosca brokers but they do not support clustering. So subscribed clients were not getting messages if they got subscribed to a different node then the node where message was published. Both nodes are behind HAProxy.
- I am currently using emqtt broker which supports clustering and the load balancing issue gets solved by that but it seems it does not support shared subscriptions across cluster nodes.

A feature like the Kafka consumer group is what is required I believe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com)? 
It offers so called [shared subscriptions](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#hivemqdocs_shared_subscriptions).

> If shared subscriptions are used, all clients which share the same subscription will receive messages in an alternating fashion.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I have read about it, but I am looking for an open source solution which either offers something like shared subscriptions or am open to hearing about how such a scenario is handled in the absence of shared subscriptions

Comment: Side node: Shared subscriptions are currently not part of the MQTT spec (3.1.1) so each implementation is different. v5 spec includes shared subscriptions as an optional component, so all implementation should be interoperable.